# Determining the amount of chlorine in a swimming pool

Tags: water, analytical-chemistry

I need to determine the amount of chlorine in a swimming pool. How do I get started? What kind of experiment would I need to carry out?
What equipment would I need for this experiment?

Answer (score 4):

If you need a no-frills solution, get some quick-test paper, such as [this](http://www.mn-net.com/Testpapers/SpezielleTestpapiere/ChlorTest/tabid/10490/language/en-US/Default.aspx).

A slightly more complex solution would be a test kit like [this](http://www.merckmillipore.com/INTL/en/product/chemicals/chlorine-test,MDA_CHEM-114434), which makes use of the formation of *Bandrowski's base* from 1,4-phenylenediamine in the presence of oxidants, such as chlorine.